# pymongo date filter with d-m-y format date in database

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

pymongo code:

```
    mycol  = mydb["anomaly_output"]

    from_date = datetime.strptime("01-01-2018", '%d-%m-%Y')
    to_date   = datetime.strptime("01-01-2020", '%d-%m-%Y')

    from_date = str(from_date.isoformat())
    to_date   = str(to_date.isoformat())

    data  = json.loads(dumps(mycol.find({"Date": { "$gte": from_date, "$lt": to_date }})))
```

Date format in my database :

```
"Date": "01-04-2020"
```

Here is my code shared. This is how i am trying to filter by date
but, unfortunately i am getting empty result.

Please have a look

Comment: try using from_date and to_date and passing them as python DateTime objects to the find query instead of str.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your date variables are in the python datetime format it will be compatible with the ISODate format of Mongo and you dont have to convert to string ( this string conversion is rendering the filters ineffective I feel) . . This is step is not needed :

`from_date = str(from_date.isoformat())

to_date   = str(to_date.isoformat())`